# Why is $E(\lvert X\rvert^p e^{\theta X})<\infty$ for $p\ge0$ if $\varphi_X(\theta) < \infty$?

Tags: integration, probability-theory, expected-value, moment-generating-functions, large-deviation-theory

This statement was just thrown out there in a proof for Cramers Large Deviation Theorem:

If $\varphi_X(\theta) = E(e^{\theta X}) < \infty$ on an open neighborhood of $\theta_0$ then
$$E(\lvert X\rvert^p e^{\theta X})<\infty,\quad 0\le p \in\mathbb{R}$$
I don't see why this is obvious, and when I tried to look at the integral for the expected value, it didn't get any clearer.

I don't really have any ideas, so little is known about $X$ (it's just a real-valued RV).

How can I show this result?

Comment: [Probability theory](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_theory) is [about the measure-theoretic foundations](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8587/290189) of stochastics.  The tag ([tag:probability-theory]) is used on math.SE for questions concerning this subject.

Comment: maybe you can try thinking of $e^{\theta X}$ as an infinite series, so that it can "absorb" $|X|^p$.  Try make use of the boundedness of the Laplace transform of $X$ to limit the "probability of explosion" $P(|X|>M)<{\rm something}(\epsilon)$.

Comment: It's about making some bounds, say $x < x^{1.5} < x^2$ for $x > 1$.  You may adapt the $x>1$ here to a suitable domain.

Comment: @RubenKruepper: This is because for any $\theta_1> \theta_2>0$ and $p \ge 0 $, you can find two numbers $C_1,C_2$ such that: $$ e^{\theta_1 x } \ge C_1e^{\theta_2x} x^p$$ whenever $x\ge0 $ , and $$ |x|^p e^{\theta_2x }<C_2$$ whenever $x<0$

Comment: The case when $\theta=0$ is not really covered by the above observation. However, it is a trivial case.

Comment: And if you only have the bound for a fixed $\theta$, then I would highly doubt the conclusion. The main reason for my doubt is also the reason why we have to treat the case when $x<0$ and $x>0$ seperately.